Hive SQL case when + cast can not return correct answer
When I am using case when to trans string to float data, it can not get a correct response.
The SQL is right here:

input:  one_data is a map where with key and value
output: get the right value into float value.

SQL:
select 
    case 
        when one_data["name1"] is not null 
            then cast(one_data["name1"] as float) 
            else 0.0 
    end as name1_value 

When I run it, I get a negative value like this:
one_data["name1"]="123" 
name1_value = -123

What is the right answer to use SQL
